# working with display multiple tables from database in single view using enity frmwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am working with display multiple tables from database in  single view 
butt show the

> `"<pre lang="JavaScript">System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject&#39; does not contain a definition for &#39;Bus&#39;</pre>"`

how to solve my problem?
 here is Model:

```
<pre lang="C#">public class ViewModel1
   {
       public class Bus
       {
           public int Id { get; set; }
           public string BusName { get; set; }

       }

       public class Route
       {
           public int RouteId { get; set; }
           public string RouteNo { get; set; }
       }

       public class MyViewModel
       {
           public List&lt;Bus&gt; Buses { get; set; }
           public List&lt;Route&gt; Routes { get; set; }
       }

   }</pre>
```

here is Controller

```
<pre lang="C#">private GpsinformarEntities db = new GpsinformarEntities();
        /// Multiple Model in single view using Dynamic View
        /// &lt;/summary&gt;
        /// &lt;returns&gt;&lt;/returns&gt;
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            mymodel.buss = GetBus();
            mymodel.Students = GetRoute();
            return View(mymodel);
        }


        public List&lt;Bus&gt; GetBus()
        {
            List&lt;Bus&gt; buss = new List&lt;Bus&gt;();
            return buss = db.Buses.ToList();

        }

        public List&lt;Route&gt; GetRoute()
        {
            List&lt;Route&gt; routee = new List&lt;Route&gt;();
            return routee = db.Routes.ToList();
        }
    }</pre>
```

here is View

```
@using new_app.Models;
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<p><b>Bus List</b></p>

<table>
    <tr>

        <th>BusName</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Bus item in Model.Bus)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.BusName</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>

<p><b>Route list</b></p>

<table>
    <tr>

        <th>Route</th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Route)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.RouteNo</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: In your controller, you assign `mymodel.buss`, but in your view, you call `Model.Bus`. It's better to use strongly typed view to avoid cases like this.

Comment: how to solve this problm

Comment: Try change `mymodel.buss` to `mymodel.Bus` and `mymodel.Students` to `mymodel.Route`